# Conditionally select ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I have a UI component that I'm trying to keep flexible by supporting two different data formats.

I'd like to conditionally pick which scope property is paired with the `ng-model` of an `input` element.

This code does not work, but it expresses my intent:

```
<input type="text"
       ng-model="treeNode.attachedEntity.name || treeNode.name"
/>
```

The following code works, but duplicates a lot (this example is simple, but in the real application there is a lot of behavior attached to this input)

```
<!-- Rename File -->
<input ng-if="!treeNode.attachedEntity"
       ng-model="treeNode.name"
       type="text"/>
<!-- Rename Folder -->
<input ng-if="treeNode.attachedEntity"
     ng-model="treeNode.attachedEntity.name"
     type="text"/>
```

The background, if it helps: This models something like a filesystem, where objects are attached to treeNode representing a folder structure. A treeNode without an attached object is a folder. I want a rename action that decides whether to rename the folder or file depending on what object it's operating on.

Any way I can build this so that the template code is simpler? A directive that extends ng-model? An option for ng-model I don't know about? A getter function in the controller that returns the right model?

Thanks!

Comment: A getter function would be my first instinct. But getting creative, you could refer to a different property on an object of models depending on a property on the repeater field, or whatever you're using. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/byLor7D7iIU4XzIFWBgc?p=preview)

Comment: yes a getter would be the way to go i think something like ng-model="getModel(param)[property]" where getModel would return a reference to the object which propery you want to observe the downside is that you would have to return the objects reference and not the property to keep the link.

Comment: something like http://jsfiddle.net/NhPEN/ could ilustrate my point. very simple and w/o sense but demostrate how you can use a function to retrieve an object and use its property as model, you can use other function to generate the property name and make it completely dynamic

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon I updated your example to fit my use case more exactly, and got to simplify a bit on the way: http://jsfiddle.net/tewaW/1/ Your solution is perfect, I didn't know you could use a getter in an ng-model. If you want to post it as an answer we can close this question out :)

Comment: @MorganDelaney I like that solution too. It'd work really well if the objects were keyed by type (or a good fit for storing in keys by type).

Comment: actually the advantage of using this approach is that you can comeup with any logic you want to provide the model object. if you where to access socpe properties directly based on a function you should obly have to return the scope object and tat would do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes a getter would be the way to go i think something like

```
ng-model="getModel(param)[property]"
```

where getModel would return a reference to the object which propery you want to observe the downside is that you would have to return the objects reference and not the property to keep the link.

something like http://jsfiddle.net/NhPEN/ could illustrate my point. very simple and w/o sense but demonstrate how you can use a function to retrieve an object and use its property as model, you can use other function to generate the property name and make it completely dynamic

Comment: Thanks, this just saved me!